# Meshlab Filter won't work

Tags: meshlab

Basically I have a .ply file, a dense pointcloud, and I would like to import it in meshlab, and use a Filter->Screened Poisson Surface Reconstruction on the file, all of this in the command prompt.

I open the command prompt in the MeshLab folder, and I use the following command:

cmd /c meshlabserver -i option-0000.ply -o surface.ply -s filter_screened_poisson.xml

After this, I get the following error:
          Failure in opening script
          Failed to apply script file

I have no idea what I miss, this should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can meshlab use xml files for scripts?  I always use .mlx files (which I think is xml format).  Also, you can try to do it manually and see if you have any problems - open meshlab, import your .ply file and then, filters-->show current script, then open your script.
Also, the screened poisson requires the points to have normals.

Lastly, I have had problems using meshlab2016 screen poisson, I use the poisson program straight from the source which you also run from the command line:
http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Code/PoissonRecon/Version9.011/

You will have to convert it to a .xyz file which you can do using meshlabserver:
%meshlabserverPath% -i %%X -o %%~nX.xyz -m vn
%poissonreconx64Path% --in %%X --out %%~nX_poisson.ply --depth 10 --pointWeight 0